# Method after onActivityCreated of FragmentActivity

Tags: android, methods, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

I have `FragmentActivity` and several fragments. To change/update these fragments I have to wait for `onActivityCreated` of each fragment. Is there method of `FragmentActivity` which calls after that all `onActivityCreated` methods were called?

Thanks.

Comment: If you always know how many fragments are attached to your Activity, you can make a listener interface, and have the Activity implement it. Override `onActivityCreated()` so that the Fragment notifies the Activity that is has finished. Something like [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) but instead of Fragment to Fragment communication, Fragment to Activity communication.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its a method of `FragmentActivity.onActivityCreated(Bundle)` tells the fragment that its activity has completed its own `Activity.onCreate()`. So it always called after `onCreateView()`.

Called when the fragment's activity has been created and this fragment's view hierarchy instantiated. It can be used to do final initialization once these pieces are in place, such as retrieving views or restoring state. It is also useful for fragments that use `setRetainInstance(boolean)` to retain their instance, as this callback tells the fragment when it is fully associated with the new activity instance. This is called after `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)` and before `onViewStateRestored(Bundle)`.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find onActivityCreated here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Comment: You will find it here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: Its available in API level 11 only.

Comment: Yeah, I know it. But I need to know when all methods(onActivityCreated) of all fragments were called.

Comment: It will be called after onCreateView() method called of Fragments.

Comment: @GrIsHu The OP is asking for a callback method to be used in an `Activity`. Your answer talks about the `Fragment`'s `onActivityCreated()`, which the OP is aware of. Additionally, he is right, `FragmentActivity#onActivityCreated(Bundle)` does not exist, you mixed up the class names.